# Coefficient (or target) category for factorization homology

Tags: homotopy-theory, cohomology, operads, infinity-categories

In the article "Factorization homology of topological manifolds" by Ayala and Francis, a symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category $\mathcal{V}$ is fixed as the target or coefficient category. This category is absolutely key because it massively influences the behaviour of the resulting homology theory.

In Definition 3.4 of said article there are some assumptions on $\mathcal{V}$, namely $\otimes$-presentability. This is needed for the main Theorems of the article to work.

Examples include spaces and differential graded modules over a ring.

Can someone give more examples and non-examples?

More concretely, will cdgas or dgas (or adapted version thereof?) satisfy the hypotheses? What about, more generally, algebras over operads?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: So you want examples of categories which are (not) symmetric monoidal?

Comment: No, symmetric monoidal is fine. For instance, cdgas and dgas are symmetric monoidal.

Comment: So what kind of (non) examples are you looking for? I'd like to understand your question.

Comment: First of all: Are dga and cdga admissible target? They are not listed as examples by Ayala/Francis. (I will edit the question to clarify)

Comment: What symmetric monoidal structure are you putting on cdga?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One rich source of examples is that every combinatorial symmetric
monoidal model category gives rise to such a category V.

In particular, this covers all the examples in the main post,
including cdgas, which do form such a model category with
tensor product as the monoidal structure.

Comment: Thank you. So "all the examples" includes also dgas (not cdgas). I expected there some problem with the monoidal structure.

Comment: @Faelvirin: First of all, the model structure must exist.  For cdga this requires characteristic 0, for dgas there are no restrictions.  Secondly, the monoidal structure matters.  For cdgas the monoidal structure is the coproduct, so is easy to treat.  For dgas, if you take the usual tensor product of dgas, it also gives a monoidal model structure because chain complexes form a tractable model category.

Comment: Ok, I had some problems to believe that dgas with the tensor product you described are really $\otimes$-presentable because the colimits in dgas so mit dem to distribute over $\otimes$.

Comment: @Faelvirin: Yes, I guess I should've said that the monoidal structure is model, but not closed, so it doesn't give an example of a presentable closed symmetric monoidal ∞-category.

Comment: So dgas so not satisfy the hypotheses. Any way to get around this?

Comment: @Faelvirin: Yes.  dgas, and, more generally, homotopy coherent monoids, are precisely homotopy-invariant factorization algebras over a line.  So dga-valued factorization over X are chain complex-valued factorization algebras over X×I, homotopy invariant in the direction of I.  With respect to this, I am not sure why one would want to consider dga-valued factorization algebras in the first place.

Comment: Yes, this is the workaround I was also thinking about. Thanks, I will see whether this solves my problems. :)